# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 , i cant find where i done wrong

Tags: php, mysqli

```
class AirData{
    function __construct() {
            $this->connect();
            echo "start";
    }


    function connect(){
        /*connect to data base change to PDO, for securely*/
        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', DB_USER, DB_PASS);

            if (!$connection) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
            }
            mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
            $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);

            if (!$db_selected) {
                die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error());
            }
    }

    function insert($connection, $table, $fields, $values){
        $fields = implode(", ", $fields);
        $values = implode("','", $values);
        $sql="INSERT INTO $table(ID, $fields) VALUES ('', '$values')";

       /*error here something is wrong at here*/
        if(!mysqli_query($connection,$sql)){
            die('could not connect');
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}

$ALIST = new AirData;
```

i cant find what i done wrong , i switch the $connection and $sql , still not working ,  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in.

can anyone help me take a look ?

Comment: How do you pass $connection to the insert() method?

Comment: I would advise you to set `$connection` as a private property of the class and then instead using it as a parameter just use `$this->connection`.

Comment: The problem is that in `connect()` function you store the connection id to the variable `$connection`, which is local variable in this function and is destroyed when function returns. You need to store it outside of that function - see answer from sgt BOSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a private variable which will store the connection. And inside the class use it. No need to pass it through the functions. Try with -

```
class AirData{

    private $connection;
    function __construct() {
            $this->connect();
            echo "start";
    }


    function connect(){
        /*connect to data base change to PDO, for securely*/
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', DB_USER, DB_PASS);

            if (!$this->connection) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
            }
            mysqli_set_charset($this->connection, 'utf8');
            $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($this->connection, DB_NAME);

            if (!$db_selected) {
                die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error());
            }
    }

    function insert($table, $fields, $values){
        $fields = implode(", ", $fields);
        $values = implode("','", $values);
        $sql="INSERT INTO $table(ID, $fields) VALUES ('', '$values')";

       /*error here something is wrong at here*/
        if(!mysqli_query($this->connection,$sql)){
            die('could not connect');
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank it appreciate what you helped me.

Answer (score -2):

Please check your insert query. your query is not working properly so plz check it.
    and you can try query like

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO $table(ID, '$fields') VALUES ('', '$values')";
```